# One or more screenshots are under 1280x720 pixels in resolution

Tags: android, amazon-appstore

I am submitting my app to amazon store. My app passed all the test. But It is not submitting the app and says `One or more screenshots are under 1280x720 pixels in resolution`. I take the screen shots from nexus 7 device and all screenshots are of `800 × 1280`.

Please help me how to take screenshots for amazon store?

Comment: Have you tried rotating the image so it meets the requirement?

Comment: My app only works on portrait mode.

Comment: Then you will have to run an emulator with a bigger screensize so the length exceeds the required 1280 pixels. The other options is looking for an option on amazon to say you are running portrait, so they flip their requirements to match the kind of app.

Comment: It looks like you might get better help at [the amazon developer forum](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=19&start=0). But feel free to add any answer from there here as well!

Comment: Hi@turbo thanks I'll ask there.

Comment: Simple workaround for this issue is to edit each photo with 1280x720 resolution with adobe photoshop.This may not be a valid method but worth give a try.I read many articles on google with similar issues for tablet app developers.

Comment: The image section says `Between 3 and 10 PNGs or JPGs
800 x 480px, 1024 x 600px, 1280 x 720px,
1280 x 800px, 1920 x 1200px, or 2560 x 1600px
(portrait or landscape)` But My App is in portrait mode. How can I get this.

Comment: I had a different error (I was rejected for the Developer Select program) and asked for clarification. The first answer I got was, like yours, that my screenshots weren't the right size. After some back-and-forth, I finally got the proper answer. I had to insist for a while but finally got someone with a bit more knowledge to resolve my question.